# How to limit dependency scope in Maven

Tags: maven, mockito

I have a Maven project with tests using Mockito framework. I included mockito-core dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Will the mockito-core jar be added to production repository, even if it's used only for tests? How do I avoid downloading this jar in production environment (limiting it only to dev environments)?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to add the dependency as you already did:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```

But what you missed to add an appropriate scope to the dependency cause it is only neccessary for the test so this should look like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.22</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this but when I run in eclipse it downloads this jar though I have test scoped. So is it like scopes are effective only in servers (Tomcat, Weblogic, etc) ?

Comment: Sure Elcipse will download cause you can run your tests from within Eclipse so where is the problem? It will being packaged into a war file...

Answer (score 0):

**Dependency scope** is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency. Use  tag for this purpose.

There are 6 scopes available: *compile (default scope), provided, runtime, test, system and import*

**Test scope** tells to Maven that the dependency is only required for the test compilation and execution phases, and not for the use of the application itself.